# Symfony2 login stopped working

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am encountering a problem. The login on my Symfony2 website just randomly stopped working over the weekend even though I did not deploy an update. I can't identify what is causing this. There is no exception and no error message.

I can confirm that it is working on my local machine and on a pre-prod environment that runs the same code.

Login using OAuth2 (FOSOAuthServerBundle) does work though.

Any idea on what could cause this ?

***EDIT 1 :* I did try clearing cache, but now css files are loaded empty.**

***EDIT 2 :* It worked again yesterday (I did not do anything) and now it stopped working again. Has it something to do with caching or anything?**

***EDIT 3 :* Ok, it is randomly working and not working, even though I am not doing anything. It is so weird.**

Comment: Have you updated any PHP components in production through composer ?

Comment: No, I have not. Nothing has changed since it last worked (which was last friday)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve *"It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.* You're saying that nothing has changed and just that "it doesn't work". How do you think we can help you?

Comment: I cannot tell you what is wrong as I do not know. I have no error messages, no exceptions, no information about what is wrong. I think someone can help me identify the problem, what is causing this. I am no expert in Symfony2 architecture and maybe someone who is could help me find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a friend helped me. The `rootfs` partition was full. In fact, the `/tmp` folder was ***really*** big. So thanks to https://askubuntu.com/questions/380238/how-to-clean-tmp, I ran the command `find /tmp -ctime +10 -exec rm -rf {} +` which deleted all files and folders older than 10 days in the `/tmp` directory.

Now it works!

Thanks Vincent :)